# How can I ask others to verify a bug report I have filed?

Tags: discussion, bug, asking-questions

I have filed a bug report on Launchpad against a package.

I would like other users to verify this bug report.

Would asking a question on AskUbuntu for others to verify the bug be against AskUbuntu policy?

I suspect that most users just ignore or overlook this issue, and won't bother to search for an existing bug report on Launchpad to mark themselves as impacted. So I don't think my Launchpad bug report will get traction, unless I point out the issue to call attention to it.

Here is the bug I am referring to: [Check boxes in Software Updater are trimmed along left edge](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/update-manager/+bug/1927558).

[image]

Comment: This phenomena is not duplicated on my computer. Good question concerning bug reports, +1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not the site to request for people to verify your bug reports.  Filing bug reports is independent from Ask Ubuntu, and this is not a forum site, so this does not fit into the questions permitted on the help center.

Asking someone to verify a bug is tantamount, essentially, to filing a bug report on Ask Ubuntu, which is explicitly disallowed and gets those questions closed as offtopic.

Answer (score 3):

### Ubuntu Forums

If the bug is interesting you might ask for confirmation at Ubuntu Forums, (https://ubuntuforums.org/forum.php).

I have asked for and been given confirmation of bugs by users at that sight, Likewise, I have been asked to confirm bugs by users from there also.

Their rules are a little looser than here.

Comment: I was about to create a post on the forums you linked to above, when I discovered that the bug was indeed confirmed. Just to close the loop on your test above, the issue only occurs when there are multiple categories of updates "Security updates" and "Other updates". See [duplicate bug report 1772131](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/update-manager/+bug/1772131)